# how to insert csv data with images into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i have made an online examination site and i have inserted questions into mysql database through csv. And in mathematics question paper it contains some graphs and images which is not going in database. so how can i insert data with images into mysql database?

```
@$fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name']; 
$chk_ext = explode(".",$fname); 
if(strtolower(@$chk_ext[1]) == "csv") { 
    $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name']; 
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r"); 
    $q = mysql_query("select max(id) as 'key' from subject1"); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($q); 
    while (($datas = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){
        @$sql = "INSERT INTO subject1(id,question) VALUES('".$datas[0]."')";
        mysql_query($sql)
    } 
    fclose($handle);
    echo "Successfully Imported"; 
}
```

Comment: you say graphs and images are not going in database, and then you ask how insert images into database? don't make much sense.

Comment: Do you have something you have started with or you are about to start and you need direction

Comment: @$fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];        
         $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);
         if(strtolower(@$chk_ext[1]) == "csv")
         {  $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
             $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
              $q = mysql_query("select max(id) as 'key' from subject1"); $row = mysql_fetch_array($q);
             while (($datas = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){@$sql = "INSERT INTO subject1(id,question) VALUES('".$datas[0]."')";mysql_query($sql)}
             fclose($handle);echo "Successfully Imported";
         }

Comment: above is the code used to import csv file into database but it do not take images into it

Answer (score 0):

Its typically more efficient to store path values to images than the images themselves. If you are set on storing the images though, you can use a BLOB style column.